# What goes wrong when a display:inline custom element contains display:block elements?

Tags: css, polymer, shadow-dom

I'm building a custom element to mark up examples (play with it at http://jsbin.com/kiboxuca/1/edit):

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/polymer/0.2.0/platform.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/polymer/0.2.0/polymer.js"></script>
<polymer-element name="my-example" noscript>
  <template>
    <style>
      :host { display: inline }
    </style>
    [ <em>Example:</em>
    <content></content>
    — <em>end example</em> ]
  </template>
</polymer-element>
<div>
  Some text <my-example>Introduction
  <pre>Some code here</pre>
  More example</my-example>
</div>
```

This produces the appearance I want:

> Some text [ *Example:* Introduction
>
> ```
> Some code here
> ```
>
> More example — *end example* ]

However, because it makes the `<my-example>` element `display:inline` I'm worried that the block-level `<pre>` element is going to cause problems.

Styling `<my-example>` as `display:block` forces it to start on a new line, which is inconsistent with the [PDF](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3797.pdf) I need to imitate.

What sorts of problems should I expect from violating the CSS box model like this, and how can I mitigate them?

Comment: One known problem is that `<p>` elements auto-close before a `<pre>`, but that's a problem with the HTML parser, rather than the CSS box model, and I can fix it by replacing the `<pre>` with a new custom element that wraps it.

Comment: By default elements are `display: inline`, so you can ditch the `<style>`. The `<p>` closing is annoying. I had to change things over to `<div>` to get a few of the examples form the PDF to work: http://jsbin.com/xapevika/2/edit

Comment: Another thing to try is `display: inline-block` if you want something to render inline but be able to contain block-level elements.

Comment: @ScottMiles, unfortunately, `inline-block` makes the example render as a single box inside the line started by "Some text": http://jsbin.com/kiboxuca/4/edit

Answer (score 1):

This is specified in [section 9.2.1.1 of the CSS2.1 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#anonymous-block-level), which describes anonymous block boxes.

The description in the spec is pretty verbose, so I will not quote it here, but basically what happens is that the inline portions of your `<div>` element, including `<my-element>`, are relocated into anonymous block boxes surrounding the `<pre>` block box. The "Some text " bit that precedes the `<my-example>` element is contained in its own anonymous inline box, while the `<my-example>` element generates its own inline box as usual, except that it is split into the anonymous block boxes that are generated around the `<pre>` box.

While it might not make much sense for an inline box to contain a block-level box — after all, the spec does say to break it up into a bunch of anonymous boxes for the purposes of rendering — the behavior in such a case is very well-defined and therefore (or at least, it should be) reliable across browsers. You should not run into any problems aside from obscure browser bugs, of which there are none I am currently aware of, although [Chrome has been known to act downright weird with `a` elements containing block boxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23642290/ie-offsetting-and-ignoring-height-width-of-anchor-focus-outlines/23644188#23644188).

Here's an illustration:

```
<polymer-element name="my-example" noscript>
  <!-- ... -->
</polymer-element>
<div>

  <anonymous-block>
    <anonymous-inline>Some text </anonymous-inline>
    <my-example>
      [ <em>Example:</em>
      Introduction
    </my-example>
  </anonymous-block>

  <pre>Some code here</pre>

  <anonymous-block>
    <my-example>
      More example
      — <em>end example</em> ]
    </my-example>
  </anonymous-block>

</div>
```

Note of course that the `<my-example>` element isn't actually split like that — the start and end tags in this illustration delimit the *boxes* that are generated, rather than the elements themselves. In terms of the shadow DOM, the `<pre>` element is still considered a child of the `<my-example>` element, and the entire `<my-example>` element is still just one element.